# Java SSL Error: Unable to retrieve certificate chain

Tags: java, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am working with a product called hermes which is an ebXML messaging gateway. In this particular installation, Hermes needs to sign an outgoing message using a server certificate which we downloaded via IE in p12 format (.pfx) from the partner with whose platform we're integrating.

I have verified that the password is correct and I also specified the correct alias.

This certificate was also installed in Tomcat. I then ran a test on the certificate via a tool in SSLShopper.com. The issue reported by the tool were that the common name in the certificate does not match the domain name for the server. I am not sure if this may be the cause. Actually, there was no place to specify a common name when applying for the certificate. They asked for first name and last name, etc.

I should note that based on the SSLShopper test, my certificate chain is:

MyServer --> MyPartner

where MyPartner is not a CA (meaning it's not one of those listed in FF's certificated dialog).

I hope someone out there know what may be tripping me up.

**Hermes Configuration:**

```
<component id="keystore-manager-for-signature" name="Key Store Manager for Digital Signature">
<class>hk.hku.cecid.piazza.commons.security.KeyStoreManager</class>
<parameter name="keystore-location" value="/opt/mycompany/certs/MyCert.pfx"/>
<parameter name="keystore-password" value="12345678"/>
<parameter name="key-alias" value="e38a429e10666c"/>
<parameter name="key-password" value="12345678"/>
<parameter name="keystore-type" value="PKCS12"/>
<parameter name="keystore-provider" value="org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider"/>
</component>
```

**Hermes Error:**

```
2012-01-16 08:02:47 [Thread-28   ] <ERROR> <cecid.ebms.spa> <Cannot send the message>
hk.hku.cecid.piazza.commons.net.ConnectionException: Unable to send HTTP SOAP request
    by javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to retrieve certificate chain
    by java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to retrieve certificate chain
    by java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hk.hku.cecid.piazza.commons.soap.SOAPHttpConnector.send(SOAPHttpConnector.java:112)
    at hk.hku.cecid.ebms.spa.task.OutboxTask.sendMsgByHttp(OutboxTask.java:574)
    at hk.hku.cecid.ebms.spa.task.OutboxTask.execute(OutboxTask.java:444)
    at hk.hku.cecid.piazza.commons.module.ActiveThread.run(ActiveThread.java:90)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to retrieve certificate chain
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1623)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1586)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1569)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1154)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1131)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:904)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at hk.hku.cecid.piazza.commons.soap.SOAPHttpConnector.send(SOAPHttpConnector.java:84)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: While you can use the same X.509 certificate for both a TLS/SSL (e.g. HTTPS) server and signing an XML/SOAP document. It's not clear from what you're saying that you need to use that cert for a server. It sounds from this question that you've only set it up on Tomcat to try it out against SSLShopper. If it's not intended to be used for an SSL/TLS server, this would explain with the CN (or SAN) doesn't need to match the host name. Could you clarify this? Are you using it as a client-cert too?

Comment: This is a server certificate. The app server also needs to be configured with the certificate for this application. It was generate by filling out a form online at the partner's website and then downloading it via IE by exporting it or something. I wasn't the one who did this step.

Comment: If you want to use this as a server certificate, you will need it to contain a Subject Alternative Name DNS entry (see SAN extension) for the intended host name (if no SAN entry, this should be the CN). You may have to contact the issuer and re-apply for a cert.  Which version of the JRE are you using, by the way?

Comment: You did not get an SSL certificate. Based on your description of need ("sign an outgoing message") you don't want an SSL certificate. Yet you tested with SSLShopper. Why?

Answer (score 1):

SSL certs are a giant minefield of potential problems and misconfiguration: Without seeing which certificates are being delivered by the server --remember there may be, or need to be, more than one--, this is impossible to diagnose.

One very likely cause is that the server is not delivering a set of certificates that allow a full trust chain to be established. Alternatively, the root certificate that the trust path leads to may not be in Java's root certificate store.

Make sure you check out these config issues first, before looking in your code.

You cannot check trust chains easily with a browser, as they cache intermediate certificates, allowing you to miss the fact that the server *should* be delivering it, but isn't. IE may also silently look for missing intermediates at Windows Update.

Check first that a *virgin* Firefox can validate the full trust path: Install a fresh Firefox Portable, or delete the intermediate certificate cache store in your Firefox profile file `cert8.db` (when Firefox isn't running).

If this fresh-out-of-the-box Firefox does accept the cert, check that the root cert is in the Java cert store.

Only after all this, would i start picking apart the code.

If anyone wants to dig much deeper into SSL and its problems, there's some [Related talk slides [pdf]](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/File%3aSSL_paved_with_good_intentions.pdf) from [chapter meeting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/2011_08_24_Manchester) of OWASP Manchester, UK

Comment: I can say that my browser, FF 3.6 (on CentOS 5.5) wouldn't let me access my server with the given certificate (altough I can if I use Chrome from a Mac with warnings). A person from the partner company specified that I need to use a certificate without a chain, not even a CA. Could this be the issue. I am pretty new to all this SSL stuff.

Comment: @udeleng: is your certificate self-signed (i.e. is the Issuer DN the same as the Subject DN), or was it issued by your partner company's own CA?

Comment: Yes, they issued it. We used their online form to create the certificate, not local keytool.

Comment: Let me elaborate on how the app operates. I send a request using a Java client (main method) over http (not https) to an app, say SDK. This SDK app then sends the request to hermes again over http, also running in the same web container. Hermes app then is supposed to build the ebXML, sign it, and send it over HTTPS to the Partner's gateway (also hermes). Their hermes then responds back with an ebXML message over HTTPS to our hermes. So we need both a client and server certificate. I am working on the server certificate at this point.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a solution to the above issue, but our partner sent us new p12 keystore which I then configured in Tomcat and Hermes, afterwhich, everything was working as expected.